# Editing the Wordpress "Notice of Email Change" email text

Tags: php, wordpress, email

If I log in to Wordpress as an admin and change another user's email address, the following email is automatically sent to that user saying the following:

> Hi *[username]*, This notice confirms that your email was changed on *[website]*. If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at *[admin email]* This email has been sent to *[user email]* Regards, All at *[website]* *[website url]*

Is there a way to edit this message to say something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use the `email_change_email` filter. [Learn about this filter in  the WordPress Codex.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/email_change_email/) Also learn about it on [hookr.io](http://hookr.io/filters/email_change_email/)

[Learn about adding filters here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

```
    /* Filter Email Change Email Text */

    function so43532474_custom_change_email_address_change( $email_change, $user, $userdata ) {

        $new_message_txt = __( 'Change the text here, use ###USERNAME###, ###ADMIN_EMAIL###, ###EMAIL###, ###SITENAME###, ###SITEURL### tags.' );

        $email_change[ 'message' ] = $new_message_txt;

        return $email_change;

    }
    add_filter( 'email_change_email', 'so43532474_custom_change_email_address_change', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Refer here for more details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/email_change_email/

Answer (score 0):

Just edit below file from root directory located in **/wp-includes/user.php** line no. 2064 or search for **'Hi ###USERNAME###,** and you will find the message body as below that you can customize it as you would like.

```html
$email_change_text = __(
    'Hi ###USERNAME###,

This notice confirms that your email address on ###SITENAME### was changed to ###NEW_EMAIL###.

If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at
###ADMIN_EMAIL###

This email has been sent to ###EMAIL###

Regards,
All at ###SITENAME###
###SITEURL###'
                     );
```

Comment: Bad bad idea to edit a wp core file. Edit would be lost on next update. The better solution is to create a filter as mentionned by Christina.